# WCF configuration file: why do we need clientBaseAddress in Binding section?

Tags: .net, wcf

There are three sections in WCF configuration for service client: 
Look at bindings => clientBaseAddress

Why do we need to specify callback address?
Is this field required? 
Why .NET is unable to determine the address of client? 
Does it mean that i can specify client endpoint that is located on some other machine?

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address=
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name=
                 clientBaseAddress=
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name=>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are  using wshttpdualbinding, you will need ClientBaseAddress if you are running on Windows XP.  If you aren't using XP, you should be able to leave it out.

See here for more info: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wenlong/how-to-use-wsdualhttpbinding-on-windows-xp-for-hosted-services)